# Multithreading in Java Web server USER/ADMIN scenario

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, deadlock

I am solving past papers exams and currently, I am stuck on a concurrency question.

Question description :

The intended behaviour of the program is that an unlimited number
of non-admin users can use the server simultaneously; but, an admin
user must not access the server at the same time as any other user
(admin or non-admin). Write some code to be added at the place

The question asks to provide code to meet three conditions:

• Create a web server object to be used by all users

• Create 10 non-admin users (i.e. users with adminUser set to
  false), named user0, user1,...user9 and execute these as concurrent
  threads

• Create 2 admin users, named admin1 and admin2 and execute
  these as concurrent threads.

I assume, that in order to stop threads interleave, I need to call wait and notifyAll, please correct me if I am wrong.

This is my while loop conditions: `while((!u.isAdmin() && adminUsing) || (u.isAdmin() && userCount > 0) || (!u.isAdmin() && adminsWaiting > 0)){`

However, my results are not satisfying:

- [Result where the admin is connected when the user is also
  created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVTgl.png)
- [result that I have expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scqci.png)

Please help me clarify my mistake in the conditions, and help me understand how can I be sure that all those 3 points are met. This would really help me with upcoming exam.

Thanks.

Below I attach entire code

User Class:

```
public class User extends Thread {

    private WebServer server;
    private String name;
    private boolean adminUser;

    public User(WebServer webServer, String name, boolean adminUser){
        this.server = webServer;
        this.name = name;
        this.adminUser = adminUser;
    }

    public boolean isAdmin(){
        return this.adminUser;
    }

    public String getUserName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    public void run(){
        server.connectToServer(this);
        server.interact();
        server.disconnectFromServer(this);
    }
}
```

Web Server Class:

```
public class WebServer {

    private int activeUsers = 0;
    private int userCount = 0;
    private int adminsWaiting = 0;
    boolean adminUsing = false;

    public synchronized void connectToServer(User u){
        if(u.isAdmin()){
            ++adminsWaiting;
        }
        // your code goes here (1)
        while((!u.isAdmin() && adminUsing) || (u.isAdmin() && userCount > 0) || (!u.isAdmin() && adminsWaiting > 0)){
            try{
                wait();
            }
            catch(InterruptedException ie){
                ie.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if(u.isAdmin()){
            adminUsing = true;
            --adminsWaiting;
        }
        else {
            ++userCount;
        }
        System.out.println(u.getUserName() + " connected.");
    }

    public void interact(){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ie){
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void disconnectFromServer(User u){
        if(u.isAdmin()){
            adminUsing = false;
        }
        else {
            --userCount;
        }
        System.out.println(u.getUserName() + " disconnected.");
        // your code goes here (2);
        notifyAll();
    }
}
```

Main Class

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // create a web server that all users can use
        WebServer webServer = new WebServer();

        // create 10 non-admin users
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
            User tempUser = new User(webServer, "user" + i, false);
            tempUser.start();
        }

        // create 2 admin users
        for(int j = 0; j < 2; ++j){
            User tempAdmin = new User(webServer, "admin" + j, true);
            tempAdmin.start();
        }

    }

}
```

Conditions to be meet in `while()` block:

• No user may connect to the server if an admin is connected

• No admin user may connect to the server if another user is connected

• If an admin is waiting to connect non-admin users must not be
allowed to connect until the admin has finished using the server
(to prevent starvation of admins).

Comment: You could use a `ReadWriteLock` to control access between Admin and Non admin users instead of a making the whole method Synchronized .  The code could look lot simpler.  Admin users could acquire a WriteLock while other users can use a ReadLock for concurrent access.

Comment: I see now, I  will try to implement this version as well just for my reference however the exam question was requesting conditions written in an answer given by @Guts

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that your conditions in while loop are wrong.
It should be like this:

```
while(adminUsing || (u.isAdmin() && userCount > 0) || (!u.isAdmin() && adminsWaiting > 0))
```

Comment: Hi thank you for quick answer, I will take that as a reference, could you just explain, how you derived those conditions, Thanks

Comment: I showed in the output the order of users. Isn't it what you expect? Maybe I misunderstood your conditions.

Comment: You didn't put the condition about admins starvation in question. I edited answer to include that condition.

Comment: My question was edited overnight, sorry for that, I managed to tweak it myself, and I just confirmed it with yours and it does match, thanks again for support.